# my.cnf mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: php, apache, mysql, phpmyadmin

Problems:- Whenever I try to select all tables in a database the connection is just lost and unknown error is given by the server to the browser and the browser just reloads with its own error page stating that the server gave unknown error. (This is in phpmyadmin)

I tried to solve this by adding max_allowed_packet to my.cnf first time and restarting mysql , and then adding it by mysql --max_allowed_packet=32M and restarting mysql, but the changes were not reflected in mysql. The limit was still set to default which is 16M.

Can anyone please suggest possible solutions for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

restart server and try again by using command reboot

Comment: try it after updating the database

Answer (score 0):

First I'll assume you are using apache
log in to your server
run the command
tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log <== may be different depending on your install

then run the same query in phpmyadmin

watch the output of the tail command and see what it says.